# Minecraft Setblock Lever - On Position

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

What is the format for the `block data` and `data value` of a lever in the *On* position?

I read the following on the wikis but I still couldn't figure it out.

> **Bit | Values**
>
> 0x8 |     If this bit is set, the lever is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metadata value of the block determines both the direction the lever is facing as well as whether it's on or off. To "set bit 8", you simply add 8 to the metadata value:

For example, a lever facing east that is off:

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:lever 1
```

And a lever facing east that is on:

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:lever 9
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That information would have been invaluable on the wiki.